# how to make it be safe for produce and consume data by channel

Tags: go, channel

I'm a fresh to golang, here is my purpose, I wanna get 2 routines running concurrently with a common channel, consumer should be start after channel created and always get the data until channel closed, my code template is as below:

```
var userChannel chan string
for index := 0; index < *clientNums; index++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go run1()
        go run2()
    }
    wg.Wait()

}

func run1() {
   defer wg.Done()
   // ...some logic
   userChannel = make(chan string, *readUserNums)
   for index := 0; index < *readUserNums; index++ {
         //...some logic
         userChannel <- userId
         //...some logic

   }
   close(userChannel)
}
func run2() {
   for sendId := range userChannel {
       //...some logic
}
}
```

in my code, if `run2` run first it will be panic as channel haven't been create and no data in channel. how can I achieve my purpose? thank you

Comment: Either create the channel first then pass it to both functions, or have`run1` call `run2`.

Comment: yeah, I see,will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the channel first, and pass it into your goroutines, instead of storing it in a global and creating it on the fly.

Comment: okay, understood, another question, if the channel haven't been written to any data when for..range channel in `run2`, what will happen? just waiting until data inserted to channel?

Answer (score 0):

Even if no data is present on `userChannel` initially, it won't be a issue provided `userChannel` is created, here it is failing because the channel is not created.

It is always a best practice to create the channel before calling `run1` or `run2` and pass the channel.

FYI: If channel is created by if no data is present on the channel and if we try to read data from the channel it will be a blocking call and will wait until a data is received into the waiting channel.